# How often do professors regret accepting particular graduate students (i.e., "bad hires")?

Tags: advisor, supervision, recruiting

How often PIs have to deal with "bad hires" in their lab/group? I sometimes hear the PI/trainee relationship be compared to marriages, where half ends in a divorce. There are also posts like [these](http://thenewpi.blogspot.ca/2016/09/tales-of-postdocs-past-what-did-i-learn.html?m=1) that reinforce this.  Is there actual truth to this? I think most of the PIs (principal investigators) I've met have handled this situation professionally, but I do wonder how they actually feel.

Specifically: how often does it happen that professors regret hiring particular grad students? How is this typically dealt with? What is the typical nature of the problem?

Comment: You could also ask "How often do graduate students regret accepting particular professors?". I've seen a couple of PhD students who have certainly felt like this!

Comment: The nature of the problem is that half the hires are below the median.

Answer (score 45):

I've discussed this with a few line managers, I've hired a few people, and I've checked with headhunters. We all come to very similar numbers**.

Once you're doing the recruiting well, you can expect that for every five people you hire, on average one will be an extremely good hire, and three will do the job well enough. And the fifth will be regrettable, through some combination of lack of will, lack of ability, an absence of a shared understanding of what the role requires, & personality clashes. You can try moving them to different roles, get them more training, work with them to find out what they need. Sometimes one of those things will work. Sometimes, none will.

---

** <sub>My primary dataset is academia. I got similar answers from the wider market for professionals (not manual workers)</sub>

Comment: Is this for academia or the general workplace?

Comment: @RoboKaren - It has been my observation and opinion that the distinction between the two is not as strong as those who live solely in either domain have led themselves to believe.

Answer (score 30):

I've only had a handful of PhD students and postdocs. Of these, only one turned out to be a "bad hire" -- he did almost nothing in his year of candidature, and I caught him lying to me and to others more than once. After trying everything -- offering alternative projects and easier starting tasks, offering time management and planning training, directing him to free counselling services -- I and his co-supervisor implemented a performance management plan, and discontinued his scholarship when he did not respond. For me, this was a lesson to vet references carefully before taking on a student.

I also regularly host visiting Masters-level students for 3-month internships/research projects. Some of these work out better than others. Some are a little lazy or not quite intellectually up to the task, while others are fantastic. With so little at stake, none have been disasters and all have accomplished something in their time, but not all of them would have worked out as PhD students, had that been their aim.

Comment: It sounds like you went above and beyond to me.  I wouldn't fault an adviser for parting ways with a graduate student after doing less than you tried.

Answer (score 17):

From the people I have talked to (i'm a postdoc myself) it happens and it seriously sucks. Firing postdocs or throwing out students is very difficult and even if you succeed it will likely take so long that the project would be nearly over by the time the wheels of beauracracy finish grinding.

Add that to the fact that most projects only have a small number of PhD students and postdocs and it can be very difficult to salvage a research project where bad people were hired.